# rendering a view with dynamic info

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js, ejs

First, please excuse my naive question. I know there a simple answer, but I am currently learning `JavaScript` and `BackBone` simultaneously, and am running into a few problems.

I am simply trying to add a table to my view from a collection of info from my javascript file. Here is my js file:

```
(function(window,app,$){

    app.views.itemsIndex = Backbone.View.extend({
        id:"items-index",

        initialize:function(){

        },

        events:{

        },

        render:function(){
            template = new EJS({
                url:"js/templates/patron/items/itemsIndex.ejs"
            });

            this.$el.html(template.render());

            this.createDummies()

            return this;
        },

        createDummies:function(){

            var bookCollection = new app.collections.books();

            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                var book = new app.models.book({title : 'title ' + i});
                bookCollection.add(book);

                var item = new app.views.itemsItem();
                this.$el.append(item.render().el);
            };

            console.log(bookCollection);
        }
    });

})(window,window.circulationApp || {},$)
```

I get an error when I try to render the view with the error **Uncaught ReferenceError: book is not defined**

below is my ejs file:

```
<td>
    <div class="td-wrap">
        <%= book.escape('title') %></td>
    </div><!-- .td-wrap -->
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: When you are calling `template.render()` You not passing in any data to your template, so *book* is undefined.

Comment: Yes. I understand that. I how do I pass that data?

Comment: I've been using underscore templates, but I think for esj you pass it in to the render method, something like `template.render(this.model.getJSON()))`. That said I think your going about this a little wrong, but I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do, what is your views' `el`? Is *itemsIndex* supposed to be a parent view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't understand the whole thing, but from my understanding you want to render a Collection of Books via `<td>` elements

Looks EJS supports loops, so why not insert the Collection directly into the view, and loop over books ?

```
<% for (var i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {%>
    <%= books[i].escape('title'); %>
<% } %>
```

`createDummies` would return the Collection :

```
createDummies: function() {
    var bookCollection = new app.collections.books();
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        var book = new app.models.book({title : 'title ' + i});
        bookCollection.add(book);
    };
    return bookCollection;
}
```

To render it :

```
var tpl = new EJS({
    url:"js/templates/patron/items/itemsIndex.ejs"
});

var booksCollection = this.createDummies();

this.$el.html(tpl.render({books: booksCollection}));
```

Ideally in Backbone only the `render` method should be used to fill your `$el` with HTML.

Comment: I was able to adapt this to my code - thanks. I'm getting an 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'escape' of undefined' error...I thought 'escape' was a js method?

Comment: `escape` is a method of the `Model` class, and as `books` is a Collection of Models, it should work.. maybe Collection doesn't mimic Array's method, but I'm 99% sure it does. Try to print `bookCollection`